# WSO2 api manager not propagating content type header for multipart form data

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 api manager 1.10.0.
I have a problem when using multipart/form-data , in fact i noticed that **content type** header isn't propagated to my back end service and so I'm getting unsupported media type 415 HTTP error.
Please any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following property to **repository/conf/passthru-http.properties** file.
**http.headers.preserve=Content-Type**

This will preserve the content type header you send with the request and send it to the backend. If you want to preserve more such headers, you can add them to the same line with comma separated.